# File browser in R

Tags: file, r

I need to write a small R script for people who never used R before that imports a file and does some things with it. I would like to minimize user input as much as possible, and since assigning the file-path is basically all the user input required I was wondering, is it possible to get a popup screen (basically your usual "open file" screen) allowing someone to select a file (import the name as string in R or something)?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The `file.choose` function performs this, eg:

```
fname <- file.choose()

source(file.choose())
```

You may also want to look at `choose.files` (for multiple files) and `choose.dir` (for just selecting a directory path).

Comment: That won't do anything on Linux other than prompt you to type in the name of the file/files/dir - not sure what it does on MacOS X

Comment: Lousy 10 min wait time to accept an answer:)

Did some quick testing and for me it didn't work in Linux terminal but did in Rstudio, mac and windows default GUIs.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson @Sacha Epskamp I'll not change the answer since its already been accepted, but another alternative which may work in Linux is `RGtk2::GtkFileChooser`

Comment: This only works with RStudio's user interface. This does not work on command-line interface.

Answer (score 3):

The tcltk package gives you tk_choose.files.

If you want to go beyond file choosers then you can use the package to build user interfaces.

Comment: Building your own file chooser is a mugs game. Not even MS could do it right and eventually they saw sense and switched to the system provided dialogs. Also, choose Tk if you want your UI to look repugnant.

Comment: I'm not saying to build a file chooser out of tk bits. There's also gWidgets which abstracts over tcltk, Gtk, and web forms. And a zillion other SO questions on building UIs for R, I suspect..

Comment: Then this should have been a comment since the question very clearly asks for file chooser.

Comment: And I said that package:tcltk contains a file chooser. Its called tk_choose.files. I'll also edit my answer just to keep you happy.

Comment: `tk_choose.files` at least sounds like it gets round the fact that `file.choose()` presents a text box on Linux. On the other hand, some would argue that so long as that text box has TAB completion then it's actually the native UI for selecting files!

Answer (score 3):

It's worth mentioning `rChoiceDialogs::rchoose.files`.  I'm not completely sold yet, but they advertise it as being completely cross platform and fixing the annoying problem common to `choose.files` and `tk_choose.files` of popping up behind other windows.  See their vignette [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rChoiceDialogs/vignettes/rChoiceDialogs.pdf).

Comment: This **does not** really open up a file browser window. It shows text to give you options which file to open. Pretty much like opening the BIOS -- you press a number for a specific option. This may work for the command-line interfaces though.