# R: While loop input

Tags: r, input, while-loop

I am bit new to R and have a question about a program I am trying to write. I am hoping to take in files (as many as a user pleases) with a while loop (eventually using read.table on each) but it keeps breaking on me. 
Here is what I have so far:

```
cat("Please enter the full path for your files, if you have no more files to add enter 'X': ")
fil<-readLines(con="stdin", 1)
cat(fil, "\n")
while (!input=='X' | !input=='x'){
inputfile=input
input<- readline("Please enter the full path for your files, if you have no more files to add enter 'X': ")
}
if(input=='X' | input=='x'){
exit -1
}
```

When I run it (from the commandline (UNIX)) I get these results:

```
> library("lattice")
> 
> cat("Please enter the full path for your files, if you have no more files to add enter 'X': ")
Please enter the full path for your files, if you have no more files to add enter 'X': > fil<-readLines(con="stdin", 1)
x
> cat(fil, "\n")
x 
> while (!input=='X' | !input=='x'){ 
+ inputfile=input
+ input<- readline("Please enter the full path for your files, if you have no more files to add enter 'X': ")
+ }
Error: object 'input' not found
Execution halted
```

I am not quite sure how to fix the problem, but I am pretty sure that it is probably a simple problem.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: @ttmaccer: You should write that as an answer

Comment: You could try using `choose.files`

Comment: @James Do you know of a place where I can find an example of how choose.file is used?

Comment: Type `?choose.files` in the R console

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6254976/269476

Comment: @James Yes... I saw as much, but unfortunately the example they gave (if(interactive()) tk_choose.files(filter = Filters)) isn't the most obvious to a new user of R. I was hoping for more of a tutorial. I will keep a look out for one myself though. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @James The question is much more helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you first run the script input doesnt exist. Assign

```
input<-c()
```

say before your while statement or put 
`inputfile=input` 
below `input<- readline....`

Comment: Great thanks! I knew it was going to be a very silly problem but I was quite vexed by it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the underlying problem is for your issue.  It may be that you're inputting the directory path incorrectly.

Here's a solution I've used a few times.  It makes it much easier for the user.  Basically, your code will not require user input, all it requires is that you have a certain naming convention for your files.

```
setwd("Your/Working/Directory") #This doesn't change
filecontents <- 1
i <- 1
while (filecontents != 0) {
    mydata.csv <- try(read.csv(paste("CSV_file_",i,".csv", sep = ""), header = FALSE), silent = TRUE)
    if (typeof(mydata.csv) != "list") { #checks to see if the imported data is a list
        filecontents <- 0   
    }
    else {
        assign(paste('dataset',i, sep=''), mydata)
        #Whatever operations you want to do on the files.  
        i <- i + 1
    }
}
```

As you can see, the naming convention for the files is `CSV_file_n` where `n` is any number of input files (i took this code out of one of my programs, in which I load csv's).  One of the problems I kept having was `Error` messages popping up when my code looked for a file that wasn't there.  With this loop, those messages won't arise.  If it assigns the contents of a non-existant file to `mydata.csv`, it merely checks to see if `mydata.csv` is a list.  If it is, it continues operating.  If not, it stops.  If you're worried about differentiating between your data from different files within the code, just insert any relevant information about the file in a constant location within the file itself.  For example, in my csv's, My 3rd column always contained the name of the image from which I gathered the information contained in the rest of the csv.

Hope this helps you a bit, even though I see you've already got a solution :-).  It's really just an option if you want your program to be more autonomous.

Comment: This is lovely, I am not sure if I will get to use it with this particular program but I am glad to see a different way to get files. Thanks!